# How to pass in data between components (different files) in react/typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my code, I want to pass the value the user inputs in the textarea tag (which is an array split by \n) onto my other component (App.tsx)

Here is my code for the two files so far,

EdgeList:

```
interface EdgeListProps {
    onChange(edges: String[]): void;  // called when a new edge list is ready
                                 // change the type of edges so it isn't `any`
}

interface EdgeListState {
    inputValue: string;
}

/**
 * A text field that allows the user to enter the list of edges.
 * Also contains the buttons that the user will use to interact with the app.
 */
class EdgeList extends Component<EdgeListProps, EdgeListState> {

    constructor(props: EdgeListProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          inputValue: ''
        };
    }

    handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
        this.setState({
            inputValue: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handleDrawButton = () => {
        let parsed = this.state.inputValue.split('\n');
        this.props.onChange(parsed);
    }

    handleClearButton = () => {
        this.setState({
            inputValue: ''
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="edge-list">
                Edges <br/>
                <textarea
                    rows={5}
                    cols={30}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    value={this.state.inputValue}
                /> <br/>
                <button onClick={this.handleDrawButton}>Draw</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleClearButton}>Clear</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default EdgeList;
```

App:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import EdgeList from "./EdgeList";
import Map from "./Map";

// Allows us to write CSS styles inside App.css, any styles will apply to all components inside <App />
import "./App.css";

interface AppState {
    edges: String[],
    color: string;
}

class App extends Component<{}, AppState> { // <- {} means no props.\

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            edges: [],
            color: ''
        }
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 id="app-title">Line Mapper!</h1>
        <div>
          {}
          <Map />
        </div>
        <EdgeList
          onChange={(value) => {
            this.setState({
                edges: value
            });
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I need the value from parsed to be used in my App.tsx file and I'm unsure of how to make the connection/add it

Comment: You can either pass around state which is not recommended, or use `redux`, which is used in large projects

Comment: Checkout [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook, you can set it up at the root and all the child components will have access to it's state values and methods

Comment: Only if you use modern react and functional components